# What are the parameters necessary for logistic regression in Vowpal Wabbit?

Tags: machine-learning, bigdata, logistic-regression, vowpalwabbit

I am using the following parameters

```
vw -d train_output -f data.model --loss_function logistic
```

Is it the correct way to make Vowpal Wabbit understand that I want to apply logistic regression?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it looks ok.

Note: If you are doing a binary classification problem with logistic regression your labels to the training samples should be [-1,1], not [0,1]. Also you may want to add `--binary` then.

```
1 'ham |f please read this mailing list issue ...
-1 'spam |f dear friend, buy our mortgage plan ...
```

Then logistic loss and hinge loss will work fine. Else VW will throw a warning (it is communicated when you forget the argument, used a non-existent loss function argument, or your labels are not [-1,1]).

For regression problems see quantile loss or squared loss.

See:

https://github.com/JohnLangford/vowpal_wabbit/wiki/Loss-functions
https://github.com/JohnLangford/vowpal_wabbit/wiki/Command-line-arguments

Comment: `--binary` has no effect on the learned model. The resulting model is exactly the same, no matter if you used `--binary` or not. So it **does not improve performance**. It has only two effects: First, 0/1 loss is reported instead of the logistic loss (and 0/1 loss can be 1 at most, while the logistic loss is unbounded). Second, the output of `-p` (predictions) is mapped to -1 and 1 based on the sign.

Comment: You are right. I updated the answer with your correction. I misunderstood the following comment: "If you want to do classification, I'd recommend using -1/+1 labels and using --binary to get 0/1 loss rather than the default squared loss. [...] In addition '--loss_function logistic' (instead of the default 
squared loss) may give better results for binary classification." A recommendation to use it for binary classification, is different from using it improve the performance. Output from log loss run through a sigmoid will give the same predictions. Sorry for  misunderstanding and ty for reply.